# PHP Library That Generates ASCII Art Text

Tags: php, text, ascii

I'm trying to make a captcha system that isn't the same as all the others using ASCII art text. Similar to what can be found [here](http://www.network-science.de/ascii/).

Does anyone know of a library which can generate something similar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ASCII generator you linked to use the `figlet` program on the commandline, for example with [shell_exec](http://php.net/shell_exec). Figlet can be installed on most Unix machines (and is in the package repository for some GNU/Linux distributions, for example in Debian and Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

You might have a look at [Zend_Captcha](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/de/zend.captcha.html) - it has an ASCII (through figlet) adapter.