# php - echo ascii characters?

Tags: php

I have a string of ascii characters, but I'd like to know how to echo that as shown on this site for example:

http://binsearch.info/viewNFO.php?oid=50662038&server=

I can convert it to png using some library I found but I can't figure out what header to use to echo it like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's html, with the ASCII escaped using `<pre>...</pre>`. You can also just deliver the raw text using `Content-Type: text/plain`, but then you'd lose control over font-size, etc.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is "ascii art". Googling for [text to ascii art in php](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3952331/edit) will help.
Also, there's a very similar [question right here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055466/php-library-that-generates-ascii-art-text) that recommends using [figlet](http://www.figlet.org/)