# Pyramid and Inverted Pyramid

Tags: php, html

I was asked to make a pyramid and inverted pyramid using loops in **PHP**.

I don't know how to make the inverted part, and take note: The line of pyramid is based on what input you want for it's output.

This is my code:

```
$height = $_POST['height'];
if($height <= 0)
{
    echo "Please write Positive Number";
}
$spacing = $height -1; 
$base = 1; 

for ($i = 0; $i < $height; $i++) 
{ 
    for ($x = $spacing; $x > 0; $x--) 
    { 
        echo " "; 
    } 
    for ($k = 0; $k < $base; $k++) 
    { 
        echo "*"; 
    } 

    $spacing --; 
    $base ++; 
    echo "<br/>"; 
}
```

The output should be like this:

```
*
**
***
****
*****

*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: Is this... homework? One hint: `str_repeat()`.

Comment: Why not just invert the logic? After all, as written, you're already generating a decreasing pyramid, but of spaces...

Comment: Nope, this is part of our syllabus and I wanted to do it in advance .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Library That Generates ASCII Art Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055466/php-library-that-generates-ascii-art-text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
$height = $_POST['height'] = 5;

if($height <= 0)
    echo "Please write Positive Number";


for($count = 1; $count <= $height; $count++) {
    for($innerCount = 0; $innerCount < $count; $innerCount++)
        echo "*";   
    echo "<br />";

}

echo "<br />";

for($count = $height; $count > 0; $count--) {

    for($innerCount = 0; $innerCount < $count; $innerCount++)
        echo "*";   
    echo "<br />";
}
```

Output:

```
*
**
***
****
*****

*****
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: @console But it works right?

Comment: Yes, I just added some few codes. Thanks. :D

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
$height = $_POST['height'];
if ($height <= 0) {
    echo "Please write Positive Number";
} else {
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $height; $i++) {
        echo str_repeat("*", $i) . "<br />";
    }
    echo '<br />';
    for ($i = $height; $i >= 1; $i--) {
        echo str_repeat("*", $i) . "<br />";
    }
}
```

**EDITED** with validation.

Comment: A user will put his own height, he will put it on a text box and the output should be what he put in the text box

Comment: Yes, my code just for demonstration. Just simple replace the `$height = 20` to `$height = $_POST["height"];`

Answer (score 0):

*The following while loop satisfies the upside down triangle*

```
$x = 10;
while ( $x >= 1 ) {
    $y=1;
    while ($y <= $x) {
        echo "*";
        ++$y;
    }
    echo "<br/>";
    --$x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You already print pyramid but your code seems to be little bit complex for inverse try the code below

```
for ($i = $height; $i >= 0; $i--) {

      for ($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++){
         echo '*';
      }

       echo "<br/>";
   }
```